# Slow performance of find

Tags: 16.04, command-line, cron, find

I have a process that creates many nested directories and files in output  directory.  Right now the directory has 67,000 files which does not sound much.

I have a cleanup cron job setup exactly like following

```
0,30 * * * *  /usr/bin/find /tmp/<output dir>/ -mmin +60 -delete
```

What I am seeing is find command not able to clean up the directory fast enough when cron command executes it. I have some files which older than twelve hours and not yet cleaned up. I see 4 instances of find command getting piled up within last few hours.

If done on the terminal, usually find process finishes under a minute with all cleanup done, however running via cron, many times find process is not terminating and I do witness multiple instances of find command running because previous cron command didn't terminate.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Since the main goal is to clean up the files which are not updated in last hour, I'm ok to execute other commands which can do this more efficiently.

Comment: Does running that find command in bash script help rather than running it directly in cronjob?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen, Haven't tried it, will try it out. Why do you think it will make a difference?

Comment: 67,000 files DOES "sound like much". `find` has to read the `inode` for each file (to compute `-mmin`). Why not wrap the `find` command in a script? Then you can add debugging to the script. `sudo lsof -c find` will show you where each `find` is stopped.

Comment: @waltinator, it still does not answer the question why a cron job will be slow. Executing same command on terminal finishes under a minute. I'll try debugging

Comment: Still, I would expect deleting 100,000 files should take seconds at most. Using `find` should be the most efficient way to do this. @user871199, are there directories under that parent? Because the default behaviour of find is "breadth-first", you will attempt to delete a directory and then attempt to delete the files in that directory. (read the man page about the -delete option) Does the cron user have permission to delete these files?

Comment: Does your inbox and/or cron log show any errors?

Comment: @glennjackman, cron job runs as same user who creates those files. And no, there are no logs - its just that job does not terminate. One thing I have noticed is WA time shown in top goes way to high when cron jobs starts piling up. Makes sense I suppose as all those find jobs walking through directories

Comment: @glennjackman, man page for find indicates that -delete action implies depth

Comment: While you're working on this, change your cron entry to `find ... >>$HOME/find.log 2>&1` so you'll be able to see what's going on.